# sqlite3 compress function in D

Tags: sqlite, d

I'm trying to adapt the C code to compress data from http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Compress-function-tp11998p11999.html in D without any success, which is giving me `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` when run. I've tried debugging this using gdb, which seems to hint something is wrong with my call to sqlite3_exec, which is being used correctly to my knowledge.

```
import etc.c.sqlite3, etc.c.zlib;

void main(){
  sqlite3* db;
  int rc;
  char* errmsg;

  rc = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);
  rc = sqlite3_create_function(db, "compress", 1, SQLITE_UTF8, null, 
                               &sqlite_compress, null, null);
  rc = sqlite3_create_function(db, "decompress", 1, SQLITE_UTF8, null, 
                               &sqlite_decompress, null, null);
  rc = sqlite3_exec(db,
        "select decompress(compress('may the force be with you'))="
        "'may the force be with you'",
        null, null, &errmsg);
  assert(rc == SQLITE_OK);

  sqlite3_close(db);
}
extern(C){
static void sqlite_compress(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv){
  ulong rc, nIn, nOut;
  const(ubyte)* inBuf;
  ubyte* outBuf;

  inBuf = cast(ubyte*)sqlite3_value_blob(argv[0]);
  nIn = sqlite3_value_bytes(argv[0]);
  nOut = 13 + nIn + (nIn+999)/1000;
  outBuf = cast(ubyte*)sqlite3_malloc(cast(int)nOut+4);
  outBuf[0] = nIn>>24 & 0xff;
  outBuf[1] = nIn>>16 & 0xff;
  outBuf[2] = nIn>>8 & 0xff;
  outBuf[3] = nIn & 0xff;
  rc = compress(&outBuf[4], &nOut, inBuf, nIn);

  if( rc==Z_OK ){
    sqlite3_result_blob(context, &outBuf, cast(int)nOut+4, &sqlite3_free);
  }else{
    sqlite3_free(&outBuf);
    sqlite3_result_error(context, "uncompressable data", -1);
  }
}

static void sqlite_decompress(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv){
  ulong rc, nIn, nOut;
  const(ubyte)* inBuf;
  ubyte* outBuf;

  nIn = sqlite3_value_bytes(argv[0]);
  if( nIn<=4 )
    return;

  inBuf = cast(ubyte*)sqlite3_value_blob(argv[0]);
  nOut = (inBuf[0]<<24) + (inBuf[1]<<16) + (inBuf[2]<<8) + inBuf[3];
  outBuf = cast(ubyte*)sqlite3_malloc( cast(int)nOut+1 );
  rc = uncompress(outBuf, &nOut, &inBuf[4], nIn);
  if( rc==Z_OK ){
    sqlite3_result_blob(context, outBuf, cast(int)nOut, &sqlite3_free);
  }else{
    sqlite3_free(&outBuf);
    sqlite3_result_error(context, "data is not compressed", -1);
  }
}
}
```

What might be causing the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in `sqlite_compress` is the culprit:

```
sqlite3_result_blob(context, &outBuf, cast(int)nOut+4, &sqlite3_free);
```

Here's its correct counterpart in `sqlite_decompress`:

```
sqlite3_result_blob(context, outBuf, cast(int)nOut, &sqlite3_free);
```

Notice the difference? In `sqlite_compress` you're passing `&outBuf` when you should be passing `outBuf`. With `&outBuf`, `sqlite3_free` tries to free a pointer to the local variable `outBuf` which must fail.

Comment: See the line `rc = uncompress(outBuf, &nOut, &inBuf[4], nIn);`.  I used the code with my own compression method and I had to use `nIn - 4` as 4 bytes of input is used to store the original length.  However, this may not be the problem here.  Just mentioning as I came across this.